# javascript not working in while loop on button in all row except work in first row

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a web page in which I am fetching value from database and showing in table,in table I have given two button one is red and another is green.when I post some value from my index page
sql query executes and fetches value from db and shows in multiple row buttons which is also in loop show it was also show in all row. I am applying jquery on buttons - means when first button is clicked then it become green and when another button is clicked it become red. The problem is that
it worked only in 1st row buttons. In all other row button display button jquery not worked. means button not green and red after pressing.

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['var']=$_POST['casetype'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_select_db("Court1") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * from causelist WHERE CaseType='" . $_SESSION['var'] . "'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
        $_SESSION['SNo']=$info['SNo'];
        $_SESSION['CaseNo']=$info['CaseNo'];

        Print '<table width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">'; 
        Print '<tbody>';
        Print '<tr>';
        Print '<td class="blueh"  width="5px">';
        echo $_SESSION['SNo'];

        Print"</td> "; 

        Print " <td class=purpleh  width=25px  >";
        echo $_SESSION['CaseNo'];

        Print"</td> "; 

        Print" <td class=greenh width=2px >";
?>

    <form method="get" action="<?php 'save.php?$ct=$_SESSION[casetype]'?>">     
        <input type="hidden" name="green" value="1">
        <input type="submit"  name="b1" id="ButtonIdgreen" value="green"  >
    </form>
</td>
<td class= "redh" width="2px"  >

    <form method="get" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="red" value="0">
    <input type="submit" name="b2" id= "ButtonIdred" value="red" >

</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
    }
?>

My_js file

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ButtonIdred').on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('ButtonClicked1');
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ButtonIdgreen').on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
});
</script>
```

and css is

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ButtonClicked {
        background-color:#0C0;
    }

    .ButtonClicked1 {
        background-color:#F00;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Fix the grammar of the question so that the problem would be precisely understood by the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Ids are singular, you can only have one element on the page with that id. Use a class name or the element type.

```
$("table").on("click", '[type="submit"]', function() {
    var activeClass = this.value==="red" ? "ButtonClicked1" : "ButtonClicked";
    $(this).toggleClass(activeClass);
});
```

The weird thing is you are using a submit button so the form is going to submit, changing the color is not going to stick since the page is refreshing.

Comment: sir please explain me i put your code in my code but it not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create event listener, to affect all buttons on your page:

```
document.addEventListener('click', event, false);

function event(ev){
    var e = window.ev || ev;
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.tagName !== 'submit') return;
    // apply whatever style you want to the button here
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery selector

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='b1']").on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
 });

$("input[type='submit'][name='b2']").on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('ButtonClicked1');
 });
```